# Comparing two times: determine if one is on a different day

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

I have two strings that represent times, for example:

```
timeA: 11:00 PM
timeB: 5:00 AM
```

I need to figure out if both of these times fall on the same day.  So in the above example, since timeB is 5:00 AM, timeB is the next day.  If timeA was 1:00 AM, then both are on the same day.

My initial thinking was to figure out the time until midnight from both timeA and timeB and decide that way if one falls on the next day, but I'm not able to bring my thoughts together in syntax (C# or VB.NET)

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, the second time is *always* later than the first time? Otherwise the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you mean that if timeA > timeB then timeB is the next day?

Comment: Create a `DateTime` object from both of them set to the same day and see if B is before A. If it is, then B should have been the next day. Assuming my previous comment is true (i.e. you know A is always first).

Comment: Yes...you are right, I'll edit my post to include that assumption.

Comment: What happens if you do not have anything happen for 25 hours?  e.g. 11:00 AM (today); 12:00 PM (tomorrow)

Comment: 11:00 AM and 12:00 PM should be considered as in the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it safe to assume that if timeA is after timeB, then timeB is the next day? This is assuming that they are chronological.

So, in code:

```
public bool IsDifferentDays(DateTime time1, DateTime time2) {
    if (time1 > time2) {

      return true;

    }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Damn didn't realize it was so simple! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of coding:

```
bool isTimeBInNextDay = DateTime.ParseExact(timeB, @"h\:mm tt", null) < DateTime.ParseExact(timeA, @"h\:mm tt", null);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this follows the same logic as @Mitch's.